# Image thumbnail is not loading and onmousehover my images move up when hovering over an image?

Tags: javascript, html

?I am having an issue with a website i uploaded to test. They all work work fine when they are checked locally in Dreamweaver cs6 but when uploaded they do this, Roll over the images you will see the problem, when hovering over Texas longhorn image there is a problem and the Michigan state image isn't loading Anyone see my error.

Here is the code that matters Thanks for any help And the link to the site page http://odintest.co.nf/product_select.html

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("img").src=a;
    }
    </script>
<div id="main_img">
    <img id="img" src="images/placeholder.jpg"/>
</div>
   <div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='images/notredamelogo.JPG' width="200" height="150"       onmouseover='changeImage("images/notredame.JPG");'>
    <img src="images/ohiostatelogo.jpg"  onmouseover='changeImage("images/ohiostate.jpg");'>
    <a href="product_display_michigan.html"><img src='images/michiganstatelogo.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("images/michiganstate.jpg");'></a>
    <a href="product_display_template.html"><img src='images/floridagatorslogo.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("images/floridagators.jpg");'></a>
    <a href="index.html"><img src='images/texaslonghornslogo.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("images/texaslonghorns.jpg");'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the link where you uploaded the website? Can't really help much with this code.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot that http://odintest.co.nf/product_select.html

Comment: Put the link in your question so folks don't have to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what problem you're describing, but I'm guessing a hover delay. Use a javascript preloader or load them in a div with styles along the lines of `{position: absolute; left: -999em;}` to keep them offscreen. This makes the images available immediately on hover, where normally you'd see a delay while they're downloaded.
2. The image at http://odintest.co.nf/images/texaslonghorns.jpg doesn't seem to exist on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see 2 issues.

1. For me the "notredamelogo.JPG" did not load. Probably because of "JPG". Try "jpg" instead.
2. Main image does not load for texaslonghorns. That might be because the image does not exist in that directory and/or the image name or extension is not right.